# Error attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python-requests

Mi código es:

```
import sys
import pygame

from .config import *

class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode( (WIDTH,HEIGHT) )
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

        self.running = True

#ESTE config.py DESEO IMPORTAR AL PRIMER CODIGO 

WIDTH = 800 

HEIGHT = 400

TITLE = "TWENTY GAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos casos en los que puedes estar ahora, según donde tengas tu fichero config.py.

- **config.py está en el mismo directorio que el código que lo importa**: en este caso debes escribir from . import config. El '.' detrás de 'from' significa que se usa cuando usas un import relativo. Es decir, un import donde lo que importas está en la misma carpeta en la que está el fichero .py donde usas ese import.
- **config.py está en un directorio distinto que el código que lo importa**. Yo escribiría lo siguiente:

  ```
  import sys
   sys.path.append("rutadelficheroconfig")
   import config'
  ```

RECUERDA: "rutadelficheroconfig" puede ser una ruta absoluta o relativa. Si estás trabajando en un proyecto que quieres compartir con otros te aconsejo que uses rutas relativas.