# Python: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-import

En primer lugar quiero decir que aunque esta pregunta parezca ser un duplicado de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368704/error-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)
creo que no tratan lo mismo y creo que el problema de esa otra pregunta es diferente al mío. En cualquier caso creo que una explicación más para este tipo de error sería enriquecedor para la comunidad.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../CREDENTIALS")
sys.path.append("./SDK")
import consts
import client
import account_api as account
import futures_api as future
import lever_api as lever
import spot_api as spot
import swap_api as swap
import index_api as index
import option_api as option
import system_api as system
import information_api as information
import json
import datetime
import TOKENS
```

Estos imports están al principio de miprograma.py.
Este es es mi mensaje de error:
PS C:\RUTADEMIPROYECTO\MIPROYECTO> python .\miprograma.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\RUTADEMIPROYECTO\MIPROYECTO\miprograma.py", line 5, in 
import client
File "./SDK\client.py", line 3, in 
from . import consts as c, utils, exceptions
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: @CandidMoe: No entiendo el mensaje de error. Se supone que todo lo que necesito esta en la carpeta SDK y lo estoy importando como muestro en mi fragmento de código

Comment: desde dónde ruta estás corriendo tu archivo?

Comment: @Sr1871: desde 'C:/RUTADEMIPROYECTO/MIPROYECTO'

Comment: intenta entrado directamente al folder para solo ejecutar `python miprograma.py` ya que el problema es de rutas relativas

Comment: @Sr1871: He probado a meterlo todo en la misma carpeta 'SDK', el programa que ejecuto con las librerías y obtengo exactamente el mismo error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que los imports en un subdirectorio no son tan simples en Python como otros lenguajes. Hay [múltiples formas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory) de hacer esto, en tu caso debería funcionar algo así:

Crear un archivo `__init__.py` vacío en el subdirectorio **SDK** (veo que ya está)

Y los imports los harías de la siguiente forma:

```
...
from SDK import client
from SDK import account_api as account
...
```

Comment: perdona...pero no entiendo lo de 'from SDK import account_api as account' ¿no basta con poner 'from SDK import account_api?

Comment: Estoy siguiendo el mismo formato de importación que pusiste en el código de la pregunta @Mr.Baldan . Si ves, hay unos que usan alias `as` y otros no. Eso eso debería mantenerse, a menos que quieras cambiarlo en todo el código.

Comment: oooh...perdona y gracias!